# Changing IP address of ICP All in one (proxy/master/worker)

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I had a working All in one ICP 2.1.0.3 with fp1.

I would like to change it's ip.

I have this issue in systemectl status kubelet command:

> Nov 30 14:52:50 icp-aio-ee hyperkube[1712]: E1130 14:52:50.754939
>   1712 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:450:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.0....route to host Nov
>   30 14:52:50 icp-aio-ee hyperkube[1712]: E1130 14:52:50.754995    1712
>   reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:459: Failed
>   to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.0.101...route to host Nov 30
>   14:52:51 icp-aio-ee hyperkube[1712]: I1130 14:52:51.743474    1712
>   kubelet_node_status.go:289] Setting node annotation to enable volume
>   controller attach/detach
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove and add back a master node after your IBM® Cloud Private cluster is installed. Therefore, you cannot change the IP address or host name of a master node that is part of an installed cluster.

*Information from ICP 3.1.1:*
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.1.1/installing/change_node.html

Then, You Must Be Uninstalled First Then Install the ICP Again, Uninstalling IBM® Cloud Private 2.1.0.3 :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/installing/uninstalling.html

I Hope This Help You....